# Full OS setup in USB pen drive connected to a monitor with USB port

Tags: usb-drive

Are there USB drive devices where I can plug it into a monitor with USB port and boot a Ubuntu OS ?
I am asking after coming across [this](https://www.flipkart.com/intel-boxstk1aw32scl-windows-10-stk1aw32sc-atom-x5-z8300-2-gb-ddr3l-1600-32-32gb-emmc-stick-pc/p/itm3d2339de97c04?pid=MPCFVFAD5XZ5QPD5).
I'm not looking for a *live* Ubuntu OS as the data doesn't get stored in the USB flash drive. I am looking for full OS setup in the pen drive. Do such things exist ?
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/compute-stick.html

Comment: You can install Ubuntu on a USB drive, but I doubt there is an option to boot anything from a USB port of a monitor. The thing linked above is actually a full computer with RAM, CPU, GPU, HDMI output, etc. Ubuntu can run on that, but it is not a flash drive.

Comment: I have an older version of the Intel computestick. I use it for watching TV and movies that is recorded on a micro SD card and for Internet and email. I plug it into the TV at hotels when traveling, don't need to take my laptop. Literally I would not go anywhere without it. My model came with choice of Ubuntu or Windows 10 fully  installed.

Comment: I don't have the option of Ubuntu in the Intel computerstick here in India on Amazon or Flipkart. I am looking for a US based site which can deliver here.

Comment: Looking through the Internet I do not think that you can still et the computestick with Ubuntu, but you can et the stick without OS and save about $20 CD (1133 INR)  over a Windows 10 stick. I bought mine from http://www.atic.ca/ in Canada but I am in Sri Lanka now.